# Parse JSON Objects and store them in to an existing ArrayList

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a method that writes my objects in to a JSON file, is there a way I can read the objects and store them back in to an ArrayList? Ideally I would like to  store the objects in to the 'music' ArrayList.

Write to JSON method:

```
public class TimelineLayout extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel timelineLabel;
    static ArrayList<Music> music = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void saveMusic(ArrayList<Music> music, String filename) {

        String fn;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(music, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Music>>() {
        }.getType());
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        String json = gson.toJson(jsonArray);
        try {
            //write converted json data to a file named "objects.json"
            if (filename != null) {
                fn = "objects.json";
            } else {
                fn = filename + ".json";
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fn);
            writer.write(json);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Objects:

```
  [{
        "artist": "Usher",
        "title": "U got it bad",
        "genre": "Pop",
        "duration": 3.01,
        "year": 2003
    },
    {
        "artist": "Coldplay",
        "title": "Viva la vida",
        "genre": "Rock n ",
        "duration": 2.56,
        "year": 2001
    }
 ]
```

Trying to parse using GSON library:

```
public static List<Music> loadMusic() {

    ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("objects.json"));
        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(br);

        //Create generic type
        java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<Music>>() {
        }.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonElement, type);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return musicList;
}
```

Comment: You can use a JSON parser library like GSON or Jackson to do that. Google those terms for examples on how to use those libraries.

Comment: I am currently using GSON library to complete this method, although I don't seem to be having luck storing it in to an arrayList, I'll update with my current read Method.

Comment: In your try block, try using the following code:`try{BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objects.json));return gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<List<Music>>(){}.getType());}`

Comment: How do I access this ArrayList with the objects?

Comment: Instead of returning the ArrayList directly from inside the try block, you could do something like `musicList = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<List<Music>>(){}.getType());`. The `musicList` object is now an `ArrayList` filled with `Music` objects from the json file. Once you return that from the `loadMusic()` function, you can access it normally, for eg you can make a call from your `main` method like `ArrayList<Music> myMusicList = loadMusic();`. Am I understanding your question correctly? Is this helping?

Comment: What actually happens when you run your parsing code? Do you get an object back from gson? What kind of object? do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Yes what you said Chetan was exactly what I needed to hear. That works fine, and has them stored inside of an Array, Thanks!

Comment: your code is correct, but your json have an error : `"title"Roll`